# pass the object to function but can not recognize

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function process(e) {

            alert("Hello! I am an alert box1!!");
            e.hide();
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var p = $("#id1"); //jquery object  
            p.click(function() {
                process(this); //line A
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id=id1>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

the text dies not disappear when click, console reports error:

> TypeError: e.hide is not a function

but if I change to code at Line A as below

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function process(e) {

            alert("Hello! I am an alert box1!!");
            e.hide();
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var p = $("#id1"); //jquery object  
            p.click(function() {
                process(p); //change this to p, Line A
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id=id1>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

it works!!!

I also try code:

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function process(e) {

            alert("Hello! I am an alert box1!!");
            e.style.visibility = "hidden";
        };

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var p = $("#id1")[0]; //jquery object to dom object
            p.addEventListener("click", function() {
                process(this);
            });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id=id1>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

It works also.

You comment welcome

Comment: _this_ changes meaning inside functions, use _p_ or dupe _this_ to _that_ and use _that_

Comment: Inside the `click` event handler `this` is the DOM node itself and not a jQuery object.

Comment: @Andreas does it mean jquery is not 100% javascript compatible?

Comment: 1. jQuery is 100% JavaScript so there is no "compatibility"  2. No, that's just the way `this` works: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: jquery object contains the DOM object inside of it. So it's like a wrapper. If you want to create jquery object from DOM object you need to do $(domObject)

Comment: The plain DOM object doesn't have "hide" property but the jquery object has. So you need to convert it first to jquery object and then call hide on it. In the 3-rd example if you did process($(this)) then it would work.

Comment: @Ara Yeressian,I prefer to third example, inly use jquery selector while using dom event, it can be simplied when develop the app for html/javascript compatible mobile os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how javascript is handling what you are sending it using `console.log()`.

Doing `console.log(this)` gives this in the log:

`<p id="id1">If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>`

Which you can see is plain DOM object.

However, doing `console.log(p)` gives this in the log:

`[p#id1, context: document, selector: "#id1"]`

That represents a jQuery object that can be acted on. If you want jQuery to pull the object for you from `this`, wrap what you send in jQuery:

```js
function process(e){

    alert("Hello! I am an alert box1!!");
    $(e).hide(); // Wrap to convert DOM object.
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    var p =$("#id1");//jquery object  
    p.click(function(){
         process(this);//change this to p, Line A
    });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id=id1>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
```

Comment: I know $() can convert jquery object to dom, but the case above demonstrate the conflict between javascript and jquery, at least this causes the confusing

Comment: @arachide jQuery is mostly just doing javascript in the background for you. Javascript itself does not have a `.hide()` function, but `this` is a javascript keyword, not a jQuery one. So when you send the javascript object, it's not able to run `.hide()`.